# jqmShow() freezes if I submit the page before couple of seconds of timeout

Tags: struts2, jqmodal

If the button returns true, it will call the href url.
But if I submit just few seconds before timeout, the jqmShow() freezes and won't go forward and returns none. How to trigger timeout during this?

JSP:

```
 <s:a id="confirm" href="%{finaliseURL}" title="Submit" cssClass="button">Ok</s:a>
```

JavaScript:

```
 ("#confirm").click(function () {
     $('#jqmFinalise').jqmShow();
     return true;
  });
```

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by submitting a few seconds before timeout? What exactly is the timeout -- and what is the submit? Also it would be helpful to see all the elements and javascript. And yes, if the click function returns true the href will be followed. You can try return $('#jqmFinalise').jqmShow();

Comment: Do you want to say it doesn't freeze if you give it a few seconds timeout before you submit?